# jackson no such method error for getReadCapabilities while JIB image creation

Tags: gradle, jib

jib-gradle 3.2.1
gradle 6.6
java 8

In main build.gradle

```
buildscript {

dependencies {

classpath("com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind") {
            version{ strictly("2.13.2") }
        }
        classpath("com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core") {
            version{ strictly("2.13.2") }
        }
        classpath "gradle.plugin.com.google.cloud.tools:jib-gradle-plugin:3.2.1"
}}
```

In module gradle

```
apply plugin: "com.google.cloud.tools.jib"
```

while running build jibBuildTar task, I am getting the following error. I have extracted the dependency graph and no other version of jackson is there. Even I have forced the 2.13.2 version of jackson which has this erroring method.
Build is fine with normal build task.

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParser.getReadCapabilities()Lcom/fasterxml/jackson/core/util/JacksonFeatureSet;
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.<init>(DeserializationContext.java:212)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.DefaultDeserializationContext.<init>(DefaultDeserializationContext.java:50)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.DefaultDeserializationContext$Impl.<init>(DefaultDeserializationContext.java:391)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.DefaultDeserializationContext$Impl.createInstance(DefaultDeserializationContext.java:413)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.createDeserializationContext(ObjectMapper.java:4737)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._readMapAndClose(ObjectMapper.java:4666)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:3666)
        at com.google.cloud.tools.jib.json.JsonTemplateMapper.readJsonFromFile(JsonTemplateMapper.java:72)
        at com.google.cloud.tools.jib.plugins.common.globalconfig.GlobalConfig.readConfig(GlobalConfig.java:49)
        at com.google.cloud.tools.jib.plugins.common.globalconfig.GlobalConfig.readConfig(GlobalConfig.java:39)
        at com.google.cloud.tools.jib.gradle.BuildTarTask.buildTar(BuildTarTask.java:136)
```

Comment: At times, the gradle dependency graph can show wrong information and be misleading. Have you checked the following faq? https://github.com/GoogleContainerTools/jib/blob/master/docs/faq.md#i-am-seeing-method-not-found-or-class-not-found-errors-when-building

Comment: @ChanseokOh - As you can see in my main build.gradle, we are forcing higher version of jackson (2.13.2) still looks jib is using lower version where this method is not found. as per javadoc this method is intriduced in jackson 2.12.

Comment: @ChanseokOh - Also as mentioned in question, plugin is resolved in main build.gradle and applyed in module gradle only.

Comment: Gradle has a bug, so forcing a version will not help. Make sure you follow the instructions in the FAQ by doing `apply false` in the main `build.gradle`.